# Is there an easy "tqdm like" way to make a for loop to run multiprocess?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a for loop in Python that I want to run in multiple processes. I know I can use the `multiprocessing` module to achieve this, but I was wondering if there is a library that allows me to do this with a simple syntax similar to how `tqdm` works. Here is what I want to achieve:

```py
for i in some_multiprocess_library(range(100), n_processes=4):
    some_func(i)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) from Standard Library? For parallel processes you will need `ProcessPoolExecutor`

Comment: Although it is fairly easy to use (though I prefer `multiprocessing.Pool`), it is not a simple flag like the one I mentioned in the post

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map

for i in process_map(range(1_000)):
   some_func(i)
```

The same recommendations from the Python `multiprocessing` modules apply.